# On a feature phone with Opera Mini, can choosing a file to upload trigger a UI change without javascript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, nokia, opera-mini

I'm not sure I'm going to ask this the right way. I am developing for feature phones for the first time, e.g. users with limited bandwidth running Opera Mini and no javascript.

I have a form with a text box and an optional photo uploader. Most people do not upload a photo. I would like to achieve the following behavior: if the user chooses a file from the phone to be submitted in the form, the submit button text changes from "Submit" to "Submit with Photo". Is this possible without javascript?

Answer (score 2):

With out javascript answer is *no*. And my answer is *no* and with [javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wy72V/).

Let me explain.

***About javascript in Opera Mini.***

Javascript is not disabled in `Opera Mini`. You can use it. Opera Mini supports `XMLHttpRequest`, `querySelector/querySeletorAll`, for example.
`Opera Mini` has a `Presto` javascript engine on its servers which was using on desktop Opera, but with out CSS3 features which a expensive on rendering for browser.

***About forms and it elements.***

`Opera Mini` supports change event for `select` elements only. And then you change select `Opera Mini` re-render the page by reloading it with changed select value from Opera Mini server.

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wy72V/):

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <select>
        <option>Change me</option>
        <option>Im changed</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="file" id="file-control"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-control">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var submitNode = document.getElementById('submit-control');

document.getElementById('file-control').addEventListener('change', function () {
    //this will not fire in Opera Mini
    if (this.files[0]) {
        submitNode.value = 'Submit with photo';
    } else {
        submitNode.value = 'Submit';
    }
});

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function () {
    //this will work in Opera Mini and call after Opera Mini get changed page from Opera Mini server
    alert('Select was changed');
});
```

Read this to know what Opera Mini can:

1. [Opera Mini and Javascript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/)
2. [FAQ of Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/help/mini/faq). It's very useful.
3. [Opera Mini and OBML](http://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-binary-markup-language/)